# jq - get only the value without the key from a command output (json)

Tags: jq

I'm trying to use jq to get only the vale without the key from a command output,

for some reason, it doesn't parse as I see in most of the examples.

```
jenkins@10.0.0.0:/tmp$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id Build-db --query SecretString --output text
{"username":"build_write","password":"CHANGE_ME"}
```

this is my command with **jq** and the output:

```
jenkins@10.0.0.0:/tmp$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id Build-db --query SecretString --output text| jq -r '{"password"}'
{"password": "CHANGE_ME"}
```

But the expected result should be only the value: `{"CHANGE_ME"}`

Comment: the way your desired result is spelled: `{"CHANGE_ME"}` is not a valid JSON, so, do you really want the result in that non-JSON format? (just to confirm to be sure)?

Comment: well, yes.  I only care about the value

Comment: If you only care about the value, why do you want the curly braces as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Found the solution:***

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460059/jq-how-to-print-only-the-value-of-key-under-properties/460064

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id Build-db --query SecretString --output text | jq -r '"{ \(.password) }"'
```

Which returns:

```
{ CHANGE_ME }
```